# Eclipse Can't Find Files that exists

Tags: eclipse

I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to find files in Eclipse, the dialog open but not find any file.

You can see the problem in this file:

[image: file not found]

The file is not derived.

Comment: *Multiple Working Sets* - Choose the right working set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already have all my Working Sets selecteds.
You mean selected here?:  http://prntscr.com/9yi262

Comment: LoL, thanks a lot. I never have seen this icon in eclipse, and I used it for a lot of years XDDDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in your screenshot you've some working sets selected in the `Open Resource` dialog. The project from where you're trying to find resource is probably not in the selected sets.

Click on the down pointing arrow in the dialog and select appropriate working set.

[image]